# How can I put this JavaScript into WordPress?

Tags: javascript

I've got a client who is using WordPress and WooCommerce.

I'm trying to add a button to a file.  I can get the button to show up, both in the front end editor, and in the template files.  But I can't get it to function, nothing happens on hover or on click.  No matter which theme I try.

I assume it's the way WordPress handles JavaScript, but I'm not 100% sure.  What the button is supposed to do is when clicked on a pop up from myregistry.com appears and the user can then add a product to the registry.

I don't know very much JavaScript yet, I have used a little jQuery but mostly in the form of plugin's, with some minor changes here and there.

So, how could I get this to work inside of Wordpress?

Any help or tips would be great.

```
    <!-- Start AddToMyRegistry Button Tag --> 
 `<script id='scriptMyRegistryWebWidgetButtonScript' type='text/javascript'>` 
 `document.write("<img id='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton' src='http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg' onmouseover='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseover(this);' onmouseout='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseout(this);' style='border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;' onclick='CreateAddToMyRegistryWidget();' />"); 
 function ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseover(elementParam) 
 {elementParam.src = 'http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg';} 
 function ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseout(elementParam) 
 {elementParam.src = 'http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg';}` 
 `</script>` 
 `<!-- End AddToMyRegistry Button Tag -->`
```

Comment: In the template which displays your button you can use wp_enqueue_script() to include your javascript. checkout http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script .

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. Getting a JavaScript button to work properly is a **JavaScript/HTML** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Comment: @ChipBennett Oops, I submitted my comment before I saw yours.  Didn't mean to try to reopen the question.

Comment: idk... adding this script to WP does seem like a WP question.  whether the script works or not is another issue.

Comment: @helgatheviking *as written*, the question isn't WordPress specific. There are certainly *related* questions/issues that would be WordPress specific, but this question doesn't appear to get there.

Comment: @ChipBennett the Q is vague, fair enough. i interpreted it that he couldn't figure out how to add the code to his WP theme.

Answer (score 1):

you could filter it onto the end of the_content?

```
function kia_add_registry_button($content){ ?>
 $content .= "<!-- Start AddToMyRegistry Button Tag --> 
 <script id='scriptMyRegistryWebWidgetButtonScript' type='text/javascript'> 
 document.write("<img id='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton' src='http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg' onmouseover='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseover(this);' onmouseout='ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseout(this);' style='border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;' onclick='CreateAddToMyRegistryWidget();' />"); 
 function ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseover(elementParam) 
 {elementParam.src = 'http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg';} 
 function ImgAddToMyRegistryButton_onmouseout(elementParam) 
 {elementParam.src = 'http://images.myregistry.com/Images/MyRegistry/WebWidgetImages/netSol/742.jpeg';} 
 </script> 
 <!-- End AddToMyRegistry Button Tag -->";
 return $content;
<?php }
add_filter('the_content','kia_add_registry_button');
```

having just worked w/ woocommerce i know that it has quite a few hooks you could also use to attach this to.

EDIT: 
this goes into your functions.php and will add this code to the end of every post/page/product... unless we add further refinement with conditional tags.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  I have an idea of what your saying.  Sorry.. still kind of new at this.  So, the first line starting with (function), is basically saying, hey.. we need this button and we are calling it content.  The second line says.  This is what the content is.  Then the return content, i put in the template, so it returns what we just did above.  and the add_filter, I'm lost.  So, do I take the whole code and throw it into where I want, or do I add it all to my functions.php except for the return content. Sorry again, trying to grasp it.

Comment: the whole thing goes in functions.php.  explaining filters in a comment just isn't going to happen:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter  don't feel bad if you don't get it, i find them to be one of the least intuitive things and it took me a long time to understand them.